# Warning with Proguard and EndlessAdapter. App crashes

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

Have errors on exporting android app and proguard. Without using proguard, app works ok. I have com.commonsware.cwac.endless.EndlessAdapter library as third party in my code, and proguard throws that error when exporting the project...

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
        Warning: com.commonsware.cwac.endless.EndlessAdapter: can't find referenced field 'java.util.concurrent.Executor THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR' in class android.os.AsyncTask
        Warning: com.commonsware.cwac.endless.EndlessAdapter: can't find referenced method 'android.os.AsyncTask executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor,java.lang.Object[])' in class android.os.AsyncTask
            You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
        Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.
            Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
            You may need to recompile them and try again.
            Alternatively, you may have to specify the option '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
        java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
            at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
            at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
            at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
            at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Any idea? Something extra to put in my proguard-project.txt??? Thankssss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This field and this method are only available in android-11 or higher, so you should build against the target android-11 or higher. Can can still specify a different targetSdkVersion in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: I did this, set to 12 and still the same error. Not endless adapter though